# Best IPC? One app, multiple instances, same machine

Tags: .net, ipc, office-addins

I need to communicate between multiple instances of the same application on the same machine. In this case I need to broadcast to all the other instances to then have the correct one reply with data.

The specifics are I have an Office AddIn, written in C#, that runs on Word, Excel, & PowerPoint. Each instance of Word/Excel/PowerPoint creates a distinct instance of my AddIn. So I don't know how many instances I have.

When one of the Office apps creates an embedded OLE object of another of the office apps, I need to have the embedded AddIn find it's parent and communicate with it.

Comment: You might develop a gateway process, and all other processes/add-ins talk to it. Then the gateway would know how many clients are there, and how channels should be built to serve them, and broadcasting would not be a problem there.

Comment: @LexLi - Unfortunately I can't have a separate app running for this. Everything is in the Office AddIn and so we run only when Word, Excel, or PowerPoint is launched.

Comment: Then your requirements might require self-discovery of each entities, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking and once all entities are discovered, one of them can play the gateway role while others work as clients. There can of course be other approaches. I don't think an existing library or framework can easily help, but you might check Google.